# Construct a regular hexagon of specific height?

Tags: geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct a hexagon of particular height, meaning distance between the faces (not vertices)? I have seen various methods of constructing a hexagon (ruler and compass only) which are based on the length of a side, but have not seen any methods based on the distance between faces.

Just to make the question perfectly clear: ***Given a line segment of fixed length, show step-by-step how to construct a hexagon using only a straightedge and compass for which that line segment is the distance between any two faces of the hexagon***.

Comment: You mean a _regular_ hexagon, right?

Comment: For future reference: they are called *sides* of the hexagon. Faces are the $2$-dimensional parts of polyhedra (which are $3$-dimensional objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start with drawing the two parallel (infinite) lines you want to be opposite sides of your regular hexagon.
2. Draw a line intersecting them at a 60° angle, by constructing an equilateral triangle with one of two parallel lines coincident with a side of the triangle. This will become a diameter in the hexagon. This can be done by setting the compass at width greater than that between the two lines, then drawing a circle with its diameter along one of the two parallel lines. Then set the compass where the circle intersects the parallel line which lies along its diameter, and draw another circle. Where the two circles intersect beyond the other parallel line is the apex of the equilateral triangle. Draw one side of this triangle between the two parallel lines, thereby forming a 60-degree angle.
3. Bisect the 60-degree line segment to find the center of both the line segment and the hexagon. Note that where the line segment intersects with the two parallel lines are two of the vertices of the hexagon.
4. Draw the circle centered at the midpoint you just found, which passes through the intersections between the sides and the diameter. This becomes the circumcircle of your hexagon.
5. Find the two last corners by marking equal distances from the existing vertices using the compass. Note that because a hexagon contains 6 equilateral triangles, the distance from the center to each vertex will be the same as the length of each side.

Comment: Interestingly, you can use this to construct a segment of length $\sqrt{3}$. I don't know if there is an easier way, though. By the way, you could mention that (2) can be easily done with straight-edge and compass, too, without the need to actually measure any angle.

Comment: I know this construction already. This constructs the hexagon from a SIDE. I do not want to construct from the side. I want to construct from the HEIGHT. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Read the answer more carefully. You start by drawing two parallel lines whose mutual distance is your desired HEIGHT.

Comment: I guess I don't understand your step 2. How can an infinite line be the side of a triangle?

Comment: @TylerDurden: Choose two arbitrary points on the infinite line and construct an equilateral triangle with the line segment between them as the base. Extend on of the sides of that triangle until it means the other parallel line -- that is the line in step 2.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wish to construct a *regular* hexagon, i.e. a hexagon where all the sides have the same length. Also, from your question I assume that you know how to construct a hexagon with a given side length. *Thus I will show you how to compute the side length of a regular hexagon of given height.*

Observe that the diagonals of a hexagon cut it into $6$ regular triangles, all with the same side length.

[image: inscribed hexagon with diagonals drawn out]

In particular, since the height of an equilateral triangle of side $s$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} s$, it follows that the height of a regular hexagon of side $s$ is $\sqrt{3} s$. Thus a regular hexagon of prescribed height $h$ will have side length
$$
\frac{h}{\sqrt{3}}
$$

---

To construct a segment of the required length with compass and straight-edge you can for example construct an [equilateral triangle](http://www.mathopenref.com/constequilateral.html) with side
$$
\frac{2}{3} h
$$
because its height will have the required length.

<sup>Image courtesy of [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Regular_polygon_6_annotated.svg).</sup>

Comment: Is not a compass and ruler construction.

Comment: Actually it is. If you provide a height $h$ then this implies a side length $s = h/\sqrt{3}$. This side length is constructible, as division is constructible (see intercept theorem) and $\sqrt{3}$ can be taken from a suitable triangle according to Pythagoras $1^2 + b^2 = 2^2 \Rightarrow b = \sqrt{3}$. That triangle can be constructed, because a vertical can be constructed, the unit 1 can be multiplied into 2 by construction.

Comment: So if you give a segment with lenght $h$, a couple of ruler / compass constructions will lead to a segment with length $s$. And how to construct a hexagon from given length $s$ you already know.

Comment: I asked for a STEP BY STEP straightedge and compass construction, not some mathematical principle from which a construction might be inferred.

Comment: @TylerDurden No need to be rude about it. Since you said you knew of various ways to construct a regular hexagon given its side, I thought I would give you a way to compute the required side length. I should point out, though, that this is a *mathematics* Q&A site, so you shouldn't be surprised if you get a *mathematical* answer...